# Project in C++ is crashing, don't really sure why

Tags: c++

I'm getting constantly crashing when I started interacting with the program. Maybe my algorithm is inefficient or whatever because I'm still new with the coding stuff, but I don't see a sudden rise of memory or anything that is a normal crash cause.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l;
main()
{
    printf("    Minecraft Distance Calculator   \n");
    printf("1. 2D Distance Calculation\n");
    printf("2. 3D Distance Calculation\n");
    printf("3. Y-Axis calculation (for mob farms)\n");
    printf("Lower than 1 or higher than 3 will terminate the program!\n");
    printf("#");
    scanf("%d", j);
    if (j=1)
    {
        printf("Starting X:\n");
        scanf("%d", a);
        printf("Starting Z:\n");
        scanf("%d", c);
        printf("Destination X:\n");
        scanf("%d", d);
        printf("Destination Z:\n");
        scanf("%d", f);
        k = sqrt(pow(a-d, 2) + pow(c-f ,2));
        printf("Distance in 2D: %d", k);
        getch();
    }
    else if (j=2)
    {
        printf("Starting X:\n");
        scanf("%d", a);
        printf("Starting Y:\n");
        scanf("%d", b);
        printf("Starting Z:\n");
        scanf("%d", c);
        printf("Destination X:\n");
        scanf("%d", d);
        printf("Destination Y:\n");
        scanf("%d", e);
        printf("Destination Z:\n");
        scanf("%d", f);
        l = sqrt(pow(a-d, 2) + pow(b-e, 2)+ pow(c-f ,2));
        printf("Distance in 3D: %d", k);
        getch();
    }
    else if (j=3)
    {
        printf("To be coming...");

    }
    else
    {
        printf("i warned you. just hit enter to stop it.");
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The program is [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aonu4HNuuh3nkB7NRxh2dvkfhqlp)

Please forget my bad English if I do have some mistakes.

Comment: You are supposed to put a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Replace scanf("%d", j); by scanf("%d", &j); everywhere

Comment: Nobody's going to download and run your executable. If we have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then we can compile it ourselves.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you've flagged this as C++ when you've only written C...

Comment: Obvious error (though not a crashbug): in the 3d case you print `k`, but you've just put the answer in `l`.

Comment: Please edit your post with the **text** of your program.  Also *edit* your post with any input samples, the actual outputs and the expected outputs.  Please no screen snapshots.

Comment: A. This was C++, not C.

Comment: Also, please edit your post with the text of any compiler or build error messages.

Comment: Peter, you can call it C++, but when you don't use a single C++ header, function, class or idiom it is difficult for others to believe you ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that the question should contain the actual code used, or a [mcve]. This is because links to external services may break and require an extra click. You should also include all possible error messages in the question. You can see the Help section here for more information on how to ask a good question and get better help.

Comment: B. I'm not very sure where it crashed; maybe the overuse of 'if' and 'else'?

Comment: Have you used a debugger?  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: How do I even paste codes xD. They aren't all indented when I paste it.

Comment: Are you using visual studio? The use of conio.h and getch before the program exits hints that you are. If so, learn to use the (pretty good) visual studio debugger. It'll save you a lot of stress in the long run.

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks. VS has got a pretty long installing time on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have misused `scanf`. Here's a representative bit of your code:

```
int j;
/* snip */
scanf("%d", j);
```

If you read the `scanf` docs, you'll see that it basically takes *pointers* as arguments, not values. By passing in an `int` instead, you're basically telling `scanf` to grab some data from the input and write it to memory at some random location (possibly byte 0). This memory is inevitably protected, and so you get an instant crash.

You wanted to do this instead:

```
scanf("%d", &j);
```

This passing in the address of `j`, a pointer, and `scanf` correctly writes the data it read from the input to that address, which can then be read from `j` as normal.

Read the docs, read some tutorials, and don't confuse C with C++.

Comment: Downvotes without comment are supremely useless and unhelpful to everyone.